# Prove that if $S=\mathbb{N}$ and $\sum_{s\in S} f(s)=a$ then $\sum_{n=1}^\infty f(n) =a$

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f:S\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$.

Then $\sum_{s\in S} f(s)=\infty$ means For all $M\in\mathbb{R}$, there is a finite set $T\subseteq S$ such that, for all finite sets $T'\subseteq S$ that contain $T$ one has $\sum_{s\in T'} f(s)>M$

and $\sum_{s\in S} f(s)=a$ means For all $\epsilon>0$, there is a finite set $T\subseteq S$ such that, for all finite sets $T'\subseteq S$ that contain $T$, one has $|a-\sum_{s\in T'} f(s)|<\epsilon$

Prove:  If $S=\mathbb{N}$ and $\sum_{s\in S} f(s)$ converges to $a$, prove that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty f(n) =a$ (the latter meaning
the limit of the sequence of partial sums $\sum_{n=1}^N f(n)$).

So I start my proof as:

Let $f:S\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$. Suppose $S=\mathbb{N }$ and $\sum_{s\in S} f(s)=a$. That is for all $\epsilon>0$, there is a finite set $T\subseteq S$ such that, for all finite sets $T'\subseteq S$ that contain $T$, one has $|a-\sum_{s\in T'} f(s)|<\epsilon$.

Basically just writing down what I know. Then I have to wind up here: $\lim_{N\rightarrow\infty}(\sum_{n=1}^\infty f(n))=a$. I feel like this should be very easy since $S=\mathbb{N}$. The statements $\sum_{s\in S} f(s)=a$ and $\sum_{n=1}^\infty f(n) =a$ are pretty much identical. Just the first doesn't depend upon indexing of the elements. So, how can I proceed with my proof to get where I need to go?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HINT: Starting by writing out what the hypotheses mean is good. A good next step is to do the same kind of expansion of what you’re trying to prove: $\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=1}^nf(k)=a$ means that

> for each $\epsilon>0$ there is an $m_\epsilon\in\Bbb N$ such that $$\left|a-\sum_{k=1}^nf(k)\right|<\epsilon\quad\text{whenever}\quad n\ge m_\epsilon\;.\tag{1}$$

Thus, you want to start with an arbitrary $\epsilon>0$ and use the hypothesis that $\sum_{s\in S}f(s)=a$ to find a suitable $m_\epsilon$. That hypothesis tells you that there is a finite $T_\epsilon\subseteq S=\Bbb N$ such that

$$\left|a-\sum_{s\in T'}f(s)\right|<\epsilon\quad\text{whenever}\quad T'\text{ is finite and }T_\epsilon\subseteq T'\subseteq\Bbb N\;.\tag{2}$$

Somehow we should use $T_\epsilon$ to get $m_\epsilon$.

- Prove that we can replace $T_\epsilon$ with any finite subset of $\Bbb N$ that contains $T_\epsilon$, and $(2)$ will still be true. This is the key step in the argument.

In particular, we can ‘fill in the holes’ in $T_\epsilon$ by replacing it with

$$\{k\in\Bbb N:k\le\max T_\epsilon\}=\{1,2,\ldots,\max T_\epsilon\}\;.$$

Can you see how to use this to find an $m_\epsilon$ making $(1)$ true?

Answer (score 1):

Consider the convergent series 
$$\sum_{s\in\mathbb{N}} f(s)$$
with sum $a$, and label this series $A$.
Now let us order the terms in series $A$ as $f(n)$, for $n=1,2,\dotsc,$ to give the series as follows:
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} f(n),$$
and label this series $B$. For every partial sum $B_M=\sum_{n=1}^{M} f(n)$ of series $B$, there exists a subset of $\mathbb{N}$, say $T$, which gives a partial sum of $A$ containing all terms of $B_M$:
$$A_T=\sum_{s\in T} f(s).$$
We can now find a partial sum $B_N=\sum_{n=1}^{N} f(n)$ containing all terms from $A_T$. This gives the inequality,
$$
B_M\le A_T\le B_N.
$$
Since we know the sum of the convergent series $A$ is $a$ we also have $A_T\le a$, which, since $B_M\le A_T\le a$, implies $B$ will also be convergent with some limit $b$. Now if we let $M\rightarrow\infty$ in $B_M\le A_T\le B_N$, we get $b\le a\le b$, and so $b=a$. $\square$

Comment: It is not necessary that the terms be nonnegative. The definition of the convergence/existence of $\sum_{s\in S} f(s)$ is summability, and that - since the $f(s)$ are real - is equivalent to absolute summability, $\sum_{s\in S} \lvert f(s)\rvert < +\infty$.

Comment: That is correct, I spotted that as I posted. I had it back to front as convergence of $\sum_{s\in S}f(s)$ was given initially, and not after  $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}f(s)$ was considered, if it had been the other way around it would have been different. I will amend accordingly, cheers.

Comment: Note the converse situation, that if the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} f(n)$ sums to $a$, does this mean $\sum_{s\in\mathbb{N}} f(s)$ also sums to $a$? If the terms $f(s)$ are nonnegative then the sums converge to the same value, but if not we have to take into account conditional convergence: then a result of Riemann shows that for a conditionally convergent series $C$, and any number $c$ in the extended real number system, that some rearrangement of the terms in $C$ will sum to $c$. For a proof of this see Elementary Real and Complex Analysis, Georgi E. Shilov, p.201.